# VS 2008 / MSTest - how do I run a subset of all tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest

I've just started using MSTest in a Visual Studio project (NUnit has been what I've used before) and I have a few questions.

I see that if I right-click on a single test method and choose run tests, it'll test that one method.  Good.  But is there a way I can set up a test run that only does x of my tests of my choosing, instead of all y of them?  I've looked under the test menu and the options in it but I can't figure out how to do this.

Also, how can I debug a subset of my tests?  Right now if I debug my MSTest project all of them are run.  Sorry for the beginner's questions, I've been kicking around the menu options but nothing has come to me on these issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio allows creating test lists, which does exactly what you want. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182462.aspx

Also this link may be useful: http://freekleemhuis.com/2008/04/20/unit-testing-in-visual-studio-2008-part-1/

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the tips.  I did create a test list, but couldn't figure out how to get my tests into it...these articles will help.

Comment: Both of the links provided here have died since posting. I've posted an updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kona is right for a list you wish to maintain; I find a lot of the time I don't need a list that stands the test of time, just one I can run for the next few minutes/hours.

In that scenario, I use the Test View window, highlight what you I to run (<kbd>CTRL + Left Click</kbd> for multiples) and press the run button.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I'm surprised to see not in the answers is the Run Tests in Current Context. If the subset of tests you wish to run is in the same test class or same namespace you can run those as a group without doing anything with the lists or selections. 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> will run tests in the scope of the cursor.

This I find really helpful because the tests of interest (Or are likely to be affected by a change) tend to be localized into the same test class. Also the test lists are another piece to maintain. I noticed that adding new tests and renaming old tests break the list I made. And therefore the test lists are probably most useful if you have a well established group you need to test as a unit.

For instance, if the cursor is in the test itself, it will only run that test. Move up a few lines to the space between the tests and you will run all tests in that class. You can also move the cursor to outside of the class and run all tests in that namespace.

```cs
namespace Tests
{
    // Cursor here to run all tests in Tests
    [TestClass()]
    public class ClassOfTests
    {
        // Cursor here to run all Tests in this class
        [TestMethod()]
        public void MethodUnderTest_WithThisSetup_ReturnsValue()
        {
            // Cursor here to only run this test
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an updated answer on this very old question. First you need to add a `[TestCategory("name of my category goes here")]` attribute to the top of the test methods you want group together. The string defines a *trait*. You can use the Test Explorer in VS2017 to group/manage tests by trait.

There are also ways to run groups of tests from the commandline. [Here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).